# how to access variable value from ajaxJquery's method $.post() on .asp page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

This is my code on html page:

```
$.post("a.asp", {name:txt} ,function(result){
    $("span").html(result);
});
```

I want to access value of name variable on a.asp page. I have tried so many things about `Request.QueryString` but it didn't work. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `POST` the parameters are in `Request.Form`.

Only the parameters sent using `GET` are in `Request.QueryString`.

If you would like to use `Request.QueryString` you could change your code to this:

```
$.get("a.asp?name=" + txt, function(result){
    $("span").html(result);
});
```